# Normality Test result interpretation

Tags: r

I have a data set for which I need to find

1. if the distribution is normal
2. Between mean and median what should represent the central tendency of the distribution accurately ?

Following this tutorial - http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/normality-test-in-r , I did the following.

**Density plot**

[image]

**Q-Q plot**

[image]

**Shapiro-Wilk test**

```
> shapiro.test(sample(df[[colName]],5000))

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  sample(df[[colName]], 5000)
W = 0.86463, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
```

**Anderson-Darling test**

```
> ad.test(df[[colName]])

    Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  df[[colName]]
A = 213650, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
```

The general guidance I have understood is that if the p-value is > 0.05 the hypothesis that the underlying distribution is normal is true.

In the tests above I'm getting the p value as `p-value < 0.00000000000000022` rather than an exact value. How do I interpret this ? Should I use mean or median to represent the central tendency of the distribution ?

Comment: Distribution to be normal, just do some checks. See if the normal 2.5%  tails holds approx 2.5% of data so quantile check; mean=mode=median; visual distribution; chi-squared test by fitting bins of your data to quantiles of the normal (similar to qq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a question about R - you'll get similar results from any statistical language.  That said...

We can make 2 types of mistakes in this problem.  *If* the distribution is truly normal, we can wrongly conclude that the distribution is not normal.  *If* the distribution is not normal, we can wrongly conclude that it is normal.  These are called type 1 and type 2 errors, respectively.  Now, if the distribution is normal, we have a pretty good idea of how the data will behave - at least asymptotically. If the true distribution is not normal, we can't say anything about how it behaves.  Maybe it's actually a t-distribution with df = 100 - that's going to look an awful lot like normal, even though it's technically not normal. It could be exponential, log-normal, Gamma,...  not normal doesn't say anything about what it *is*, only what it *is not* (it's not normal).

Because of this asymmetry, the idea of these tests is the following:

1. Compare the observed data to what we would expect to see if it really was normal.  Measure how different our observed data is compared to what we would expect to see.
2. Calculate the probability that we see an observed difference *at least as* extreme as what we actually observed.  This is what we call the *p*-value.
3. Decide whether our *p*-value is small enough to conclude that there is no way the distribution is actually normal.

There are two tricky points here for those not familiar with statistics.  The first is understanding why we need to look at "at least as extreme" instead of just calculating the probability we see the observed data.  The reason for this is that the probability of getting *exactly* any given distance is 0. We need to look at ranges to get actual non-zero probabilities... and the range that makes the most sense here is to look at things more extreme.

The second tricky point is the conclusion.  Statistical tests work like U.S. criminal trials (or at least, how they are supposed to work).  In the same way that the defendant is innocent until proven guilty, we assume that the null hypothesis is true (the null hypothesis in this case is "the distribution is normal").  Only when the *p*-value is sufficiently small do we reject it, and say that there is enough evidence to conclude that the distribution is not normal.  Importantly, **we never prove the null hypothesis**.  If the data truly follows a t-distribution with 100 degrees of freedom, we will almost certainly fail to reject the null hypothesis, and commit a type 2 error (keeping the null hypothesis when we shouldn't).

So this brings us to the next point - how small is small enough?  One of the founding fathers of statistics, a brilliant man named R.A. Fisher decided that 0.05 seemed about right - and it's been the standard ever since.  Sometimes 0.01 or 0.1 are used instead, but 0.05 is far more common.  This cut-off has an important interpretation - it's also the probability of us committing a type 1 error - incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis when we shouldn't.

Now, to explain your results.  In your case, it does not matter whether you use 0.01, 0.05, or 0.1 - your p-values are MUCH lower than any of them.  In fact, they are small enough that the computer might start running into machine errors (the errors which occur because we are trying to represent uncountable sets using a finite number of computer bytes) - it might not even be possible to accurately calculate the exact p-value (and the exact number is almost always not that important).

With such a small p-value, the tests are stating that it is almost impossible that you would actually obtain the observed data from a normal distribution.  You can safely reject your null hypothesis, and conclude that the distribution is not normal.

### Update: mean versus median

As said in the comments, there isn't one right answer to this - it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  It's common to see advice stating that the median is used with asymmetric distributions while the mean is more common with symmetric distributions.  This is true, but I'd argue that this has more to do with the measurement of the variability than the mean.

For a symmetric distribution, a single number (e.g. the standard deviation or variance) characterizes the variability in the data pretty well.  This is the a function of the 1st and 2nd moments, and pairs nicely with the 1st moment (the mean).  For an asymmetric distribution, you need to look at the left and right sides of the distribution separately because they are different.  Let's say you capture this using the range, which also correspond to the 0th and 100th percentiles).  You could also capture this with the interquartile range (the 25th and 75th percentile) - or (even better) both.  Ultimately, these pair nicely with the median (the 50th percentile).

If your only goal is to summarize the distribution, the general rule of thumb works well (symmetric -> mean, asymmetric -> median).  If you need to take your estimate and plug it back in to another analysis, then that determines what you need.  You can also consider transformations - maybe your distribution is very skewed, but it might be normal on the log scale, and then a geometric mean/sd might be the best summary.

The take-away here:
The biggest determiner of mean vs median is what you want your audience to understand about the data.  It's not a matter of what data you *have*, it's what you *want to say* about it.

Comment: what would you think - between mean and median - the appropriate measure to represent the central tendency of such a distribution.

Comment: To my mind, this is a somewhat loaded question - each statistic says something different.  The median is an estimate of the point where half the data is above and half the data is below.  Conversely, imagine the distribution represents weight (higher value = more weight).  The mean is the balance point.  When the distribution is symmetric, the mean is in the middle (and both the mean and the median are asymptotically the same).  For a skewed distribution, it really depends on what you are trying to characterize.

Comment: the distribution represents the time to load the same web page over many iterations - would this info makes it easier ?

Comment: I edited my answer to include thoughts on mean versus median.  Hopefully that helps you decide, but you're not going to get a *this is the right answer* response (at least from me).

Comment: `symmetric -> mean, asymmetric -> mean)` - did you intent `median` for asymmetric distributions ?